# Alignment of button within a div - Currently dropped down

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if someone could assist me with this. I am trying to vertically align the close button within the alert div:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/qK3yK/4/

Whatever I seem to try, the button always sits too low, even though in theory it should be able to fit just fine in the div.

This is my css:

```
 .btn {
    letter-spacing:1px;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn_pri {
    background-color:#479ccf;
    color:#FFF;
}
.btn_pri:hover {
    background-color: #3A8BC0
}
.btn_sec {
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #479ccf;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}
.btn_sec:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED
}
.btn_close {
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    border:0;
}
```

Do I need to be clearing the float, or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the margin and padding from the button:

```
.btn {
    /*
    padding:10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/salman/qK3yK/5/

---

If the button needs padding, use negative margins to position it. Add just enough negative margin so that it balances out the padding on the button and the padding on its parent.

```
.btn {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -10px -10px -10px 0;
    /*
    padding:10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/salman/qK3yK/11/

---

Having said all that, I would use position relative-absolute since the button is placed at the bottom of div which means `float: right` will not work as expected if the alert has two or more lines.

```
.alert {
    padding: 15px;
}
.has-btn {
    position: relative;
    /* make room for button */
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.btn {
    /* reset button properties */
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    /* set height */
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    /* set position */
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 11px;
    top: 11px;
    /* for testing */
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/salman/vLjN9/

Comment: If you remove padding it will be hard to click on it as it will be really small.

Comment: We can set the `width` and `height` of the button to make it easy to click http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/qK3yK/10/ , if using `padding`, we may have to set `box-sizing:border-box` to make it work.

Comment: If size of button is an issue, add padding and use negative margins (see revised answer in 5 minutes).